# Putting a button on top of an imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, maps, surfaceview

So here is my problem. I've spent couple of days on this and didn't get anywhere. I've tried every layout possible, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Basically, I have a map of a floor and I want to make it so when you click on different parts of that floor, a new activity or a dialog box shows up. I want this to scale for all the devices. Why is this so difficult in Android? I would think that putting buttons on top of an image would be easy and made sure that it wouldn't move like in HTML.

I have been looking into Surface View, but wasn't sure if that's the best way to go? I can get the coordinates of the objects on the floor, would that help?

I want to implement this inside of an fragment. Thanks!

Comment: floor = indoor floor map, not associated with Google Maps or anything like that though. Just a personal map. 
I'm looking for guidance on how I should go about setting up that.

Comment: Creating a `View` subclass would allow you compete control over how the `View` draws itself (which would let you draw your buttons on top of a map image) and over any touch events that occur in it (which would allow you to handle clicks and launch new Activities).

Comment: Thanks Mike. I sort of used your approach. Created a SurfaceView subclass and drew the image and other things on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to have a RelativeLayout as the base layout of your 'Floor Map' fragment, with the floor image set as its background.

Then you could add buttons or any other views to the Relativelayout at the coordinates of the objects.

If you already know how many features the floor will have, you could add the buttons statically, otherwise, loop through your array of features to add them dynamically.